# Tapping on tab, scroll view scrolls down in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment-tab-host

I have two controls on the screen.

1. One is linear layout which takes half of the screen.
2. Second is fragment tab host. Which is equal to the size of screen of mobile.

So scroll view is here to scroll down and up.

Problem is that when I tap on any of the tab in fragment tab host. The scroll view scrolls down. But I want it to be on same place.

Is it possible to do this?